# Python Newbie Questions - Not printing correct values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie to python and I doing doing some OOPS concept exploring in Python.

Following is my Account class:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self,balance):
        self.__balance=int(balance)

    def deposit(self,deposit_amt):
        self.__balance=self.__balance + int(deposit_amt)

    def withdraw(self,withdraw_amt):
        withdraw_amt=int(withdraw_amt)
        self.__balance=self.__balance -- int(withdraw_amt)
        print(self.__balance)
        print("Subtracting" + str(withdraw_amt))

    def get___balance(self):
        return(self.__balance)

    def __str__(self):
        return("The Balance in the Account is " + str(self.get___balance()))
```

The `account_test` program:

```
import account
def main():
    balance_amt = input("Enter the balance amount \t")
    new_account=account.Account(int(balance_amt))


    deposit_amt=input("Enter the Deposit Amount \t")
    new_account.deposit(deposit_amt)
    print(new_account)

    withdraw_amt=input("Enter the Withdraw Amount \t")
    new_account.withdraw(withdraw_amt)
    print(new_account)


main()
```

But I am getting the wrong output:

```
Enter the balance amount    3000
Enter the Deposit Amount    400
The Balance in the Account is 3400
Enter the Withdraw Amount   300
3700
Subtracting 300
The Balance in the Account is 3700
```

When I do `withdraw` I am getting the amount added instead of subtracted. What am I doing wrong here?

Since I am newbie, I need some suggestion in my programming practice. Is my coding style appropriate?

Comment: On coding style, don't use double-underscores for the balance - just call it `self.balance`. And there's no reason to define a `get_balance` method. Python practice is to access the attribute directly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response. But what I was reading is if u want to make u r variable as private you need to add __ in front of variable so that python consider it as private variable for that class.Please correct me if I am wrong. If not how to declare a variable private in python. I know by default python wont let u , but turn around was to add __ .

Comment: There are no private variables in Python.  `__` merely does name mangling, making them hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

With the double `--` (negative) you are subtracting a negative value (i.e. adding a positive value).
A more clear explanation would look like:

```
self.__balance = self.__balance - (0 - int(withdraw_amt))
```

Therefore, change this:

```
self.__balance=self.__balance -- int(withdraw_amt)
```

To this:

```
self.__balance=self.__balance - int(withdraw_amt)
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
self.__balance -= int(withdraw_amt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.__balance=self.__balance -- int(withdraw_amt)
```

is actually parsed as

```
self.__balance=self.__balance - (- int(withdraw_amt))
```

which is to say, it is adding the withdraw amount.  try with a single `-`